# Laravel Sanctum & Laravel Echo in NuxtJS - Private Channel and Presence Channel not working

Tags: laravel, authentication, nuxt.js, pusher, laravel-sanctum

I can't handle authorization (or something else) on private and presence channels. Regular channels work fine.

I am using latest Larvel and NuxtJS with Auth-next (v5).
I am using Laravel Sanctum in SPA mode.

```
// nuxt.config.js

    echo: {
            broadcaster: 'pusher',
            key: 'mykey',
            authEndpoint: 'https://example.com/broadcasting/auth',
            wsHost: 'example.com',
            wssPort: 6001,
            disableStats: true,
            encrypted: true,
        },
```

Page:

```
mounted() {
        this.$echo.join("user.test").listen("UserTest", (e) => {
            console.log("UserTest:");
            console.log(e);
        });
},
```

routes/channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('user.test', function ($user) {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::debug('user test.'); -- log not working. As if it was not triggered at all
    return true; -- not working
    // return ['name' => $user->name]; -- not working
});
```

BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::debug('broadcast routes.'); -- works correctly
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]);
        // Broadcast::routes();

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

Events/UserTest.php

```
class UserTest implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        // return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::debug('PERSENCE.'); -- works correctly
        return new PresenceChannel('user.test');
    }
}
```

Maybe someone had a similar problem - I am asking for help or some tips.

Comment: Hi! Found a solution?